# Is it normal to invoke route.refresh() in willTransition hook?

Tags: ember.js

This question is related to EmberJS best practice. I have two routes:

1. /diners
2. /diners/register

Now that I want to reload the model of /diners after transitioning from /diners/register (as a result of a successful diner registration, using transitionToRoute).

The questions are:

- I use `this.refresh()` in actions: willTranstion; Is it normal?
  Should I do it this way?
- What are other ways to refresh the model of
  parent routes after transitioning from a child route?
- How can I can
  maintain the data consistency on client side when POSTing a new
  record to back end?

Ember version info:

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.13.11
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.13.15
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.3
```

### UPDATED with code

**Diner Register Controller:**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    save () {
      var data = this.model;
      var record = this.store.createRecord('diner', data);
      record.save().then(onFulfill, onFail);

      var self = this;
      function onFulfill () {
        Ember.$('.ui.modal').modal('destroy');

        self.transitionToRoute('diners');
      }

      function onFail (e) {
        console.error(e.message || 'Unknown error');
      }
    },

    cancel () {
      Ember.$('.ui.modal').modal('close');

      this.transitionTo('diners');
    }
  }
});
```

**Diner List Route:**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {

  page: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },
  setupController (controller, model) {
    let pageSize = 10;
    let page = this.paramsFor('diners').page;
    let total = model.meta.total;

    controller.set('model', model);

    if (page > 1) {
      controller.set('prevPage', page - 1);
    }
    else {
      controller.set('prevPage', undefined);
    }

    if (total > pageSize * page) {
      controller.set('nextPage', page + 1);
    }
    else {
      controller.set('nextPage', undefined);
    }
  },
  model (params) {
    let page = params.page || 1;

    return this.store.find('diner', {
      page
    });
  },
  actions: {
    willTransition () {
      this.refresh();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you add the registration code to the question, specifically the part where you save and transition.

Comment: @Kitler Thanks! I have updated the question as you requested. Pay attention to the last 5 lines `actions:...`